# Getting low fps on Blur (PC game)

Tags: gaming

I am trying to play Blur in single player mode but I am getting 30-35 fps.
I am playing it at 1920x1080 with GTX 1050 Ti and a Intel 7700HQ (2.8 with upto 3.8 turbo boost).
Now that might not be the fastest system but it should run this game atleast above 100 fps since recommended gpu for it is Gefore 7700. So can anyone tell what might be the issue?

Comment: Might have to try compatibility mode of some kind?  Older games on newer hardware create issues.  @Tetsujin, your comments are rude and ignorant.

Answer (score 0):

Blur was created using the Horizon engine (According to this Wiki article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blur_(video_game)) which itself was released in the late 90's, long before multi-core and multi-thread processors became common and even more so for GPU centered games.

What this means is your processor, while decent, is doing almost all of the work for the game so it's bottl0-necking and you're getting lag.

Comment: ok but according to game debate its recommended cpu is core 2 duo E4400 2.0Ghz so I think (not sure) that even if we talk about single core, even then 2.8ghz (mine) should perform better than 2.0ghz (recommended). Or this does not work like that?

Comment: You have to remember that yours is not a desktop processor so doesn't have all the features that a fully featured desktop pc has.

Comment: ok. I'll just play with that fps. that's the only option I guess

Comment: Bear in mind many 360 games were actually "720p30" native. I think Bluris one. This means they spent their time making it work for 720p resolution @ 30fps and let the console handle the upsampling.